# MySQL Query Error Validation

Tags: mysql

I running a Mysql Query to select some data, Sometimes i get a error called

```
mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

when i executed this following code,

```
$result   = $this->db->execute($sql);
for ($i = 0; $data[$i + 1] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $i++);
array_pop($data);
```

how do i optimize this coding to prevent any errors ?

is there anything wrong with it ? should i ignore this error ?

Comment: Do not practice using mysql_ anymore, it's somehow deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that the query is buggy, whyever, most likely because you construct it using components from sources which you do not really check enough. A buggy statement throws an error (since no result can be computed). That error is returned as `false` instead of a mysql result ressource. Since you do not check if the query succeeded but blindly try to retrieve details from the result, you get this second error.

So there are *four* things you have to invest into:

1. you should *always* check if a query succeeded at all: 
   enclose your query into a conditional: `if (FALSE!==($result=$this->db->execute($sql)))` and only retrieve from the result ressource if that condition resolves to `true`.
2. make sure you really (really!) check *all* input data you use to construct your query. Checking here also means to encode and escape it correctly, also see point 4. for this.
3. in cases like this it is important to analyze *what* exactly it is that is going wrong. There is little sense in *guessing* what *might* be going wrong. So in addition to checking if the query succeeded at all (1.) you should also take a look at the error message mysql throws if this is not the case. Use the method `mysql_error()` for this. It is well documented just as every other function too.
4. you should rework your code and migrate from phps old, long deprecated mysql extension to either `mysqli` or `PDO`. Both are php extensions that offer more security against constructing buggy statements. Read about "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" for this.